# Java サーブレット&JSPとJavaScriptについて

Tags: javascript, java

初めて質問させていただきます。質問文に判りにくいところなど多いかもしれませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

現在JavaのサーブレットとJSPでログインフォーム付きの商品登録、検索、更新機能を備えたアプリケーションを制作しております。データベースはMySQLを使っています。

ひとまず機能そのものは完成しまして、データベースとの連携もできているんですが、JavaScriptでのポップアップ表示について困っております。

悩んでいる点を挙げていきますと、

①ログイン認証時のポップアップ表示

・「no」と「pass」を入力するフォームがあり、どちらかの未入力チェックをした上でのポップアップ表示はできましたが、入力されたデータがDB内に存在するのかどうかを判定して照合した上でのポップアップ表示ができません。

②商品登録時のポップアップ表示

・「product_code」というものをキーに登録するんですが、これも未入力時はよいものの、DB登録済みデータと重複チェックした上での処理をJavaScriptに伝える術がわかりません。

③商品検索時のポップアップ表示

・②と同じような感じで、これも上述のキーを基にDB検索をかけるのですが、DB内に該当するデータがない場合ははじく。という処理がJavaScriptで書けません。

以上、3つのポップアップ表示で苦戦しています。サーブレット側では機能実装できており、上の3つのケースでもチェックを実現できていますが、JavaScriptの方が想像もつきません。サーブレット&JSPだけでエラーメッセージ表示とかならできますが、どうしてもJavaScriptを使いたいため、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コードがあれば回答が付きやすいと思われます。これらが参考になれば。[Unable to display login error message on modal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46123138/9014308), [Displaying MySQL Query Results from Servlet to JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13410284/9014308), [Display Data from database in Popup Window Using Ajax in JSP](https://www.roseindia.net/jsp/pop-window.shtml)

Comment: ありがとうございます！早速試させていただきます！次回から必ずコードも掲載するようにします！

Comment: @user31658さん、解決したら自己回答でコードを掲載してもいいですし、未解決なら質問内容に追記すれば良いでしょう。